# CentOS7 based SSH rkt container: PAM session setup fails

Tags: ssh, centos-7, pam

I am unable to login into a SSH host running in a CentOS7 based rkt container because the PAM session setup never completes - even with logging set to DEBUG3 there's no error message - logs just end with `sshd[10]: debug3: PAM: opening session` which on client side leads to `Write failed: Broken pipe`. The SSH daemon continues to run.

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.93 2014/01/10 05:59:19 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
LogLevel DEBUG3

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and may cause several
# problems.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox     # Default for new installations.
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

`/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session optional pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```

The server side log: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3Ki955n4).
It ends with:

```
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: Accepted publickey for root from 172.16.28.1 port 45040 ssh2: RSA dc:7b:dc:02:bd:87:0b:7a:ad:a0:71:78:e4:18:86:5
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug1: monitor_child_preauth: root has been authenticated by privileged process
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_get_keystate: Waiting for new keys
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 26
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_newkeys_from_blob: 0x7eff5524bd40(138)
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_get_keystate: Waiting for second key
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_newkeys_from_blob: 0x7eff5524bd40(138)
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_get_keystate: Getting compression state
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_get_keystate: Getting Network I/O buffers
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 122
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 123
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 1 pkalg ssh-rsa [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_do_pam_account entering [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 102 [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 103 [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_do_pam_account returning 1 [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_send_keystate: Sending new keys: 0x7eff55233ce0 0x7eff552382d0 [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_newkeys_to_blob: converting 0x7eff55233ce0 [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_newkeys_to_blob: converting 0x7eff552382d0 [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_send_keystate: New keys have been sent [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_send_keystate: Sending compression state [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 26 [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_send_keystate: Finished sending state [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 122 [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 123 [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_share_sync: Share sync
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: mm_share_sync: Share sync end
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: ssh_sandbox_parent_finish: finished
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug1: SELinux support disabled
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
Aug 14 09:55:06 rkt-1f29b259-f7a3-45a3-912a-58f401f8da79 sshd[10]: debug3: PAM: opening session
```

The client side log: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/gaWbHt3N)

If I disable PAM (which is not supported on RHEL & CentOS but just to test), the session is established and immediately terminated by the client (I'll post the pastebin in a comment). I also tried to ...

- comment out UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
- disabled SELinux in the container (turns out that apparently it's not even installed inside)

without noticable effect. Does anybody know what could make PAM behave so badly that there's not even an error message? I've seen in many other threads that PAM makes problems in combination with chroot but there are still explicit error messages, here it seems like a sudden death... (the sshd still runs)

P.S: could somebody with enough reputation create a rkt tag please? Thx

Comment: Pastebin for the server side log with disabled PAM: https://pastebin.com/nnKpg5Z4

Comment: What is the users, you are connecting to, shell in the container?

Comment: @Jakuje: root. There's no other user in the container by default